# Machine learning algorithm which gives multiple outputs mapped from single input

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, ocr

I need some help, i am working on a problem where i have the OCR of an image of an invoice and i want to extract certain data from it like invoice number, amount, date etc which is all present within the OCR. I tried with the classification model where i was individually passing each sentence from the OCR to the model and to predict it the invoice number or date or anything else, but this approach takes a lot of time and i don't think this is the right approach.

So, i was thinking whether there is an algorithm where i can have an input string and have outputs mapped from that string like, invoice number, date and amount are present within the string.

E.g:

```
Inp string: The invoice 1234 is due on 12 oct 2018 with amount of 287 
Output: Invoice Number: 1234, Date: 12 oct 2018, Amount 287
```

So, my question is, is there an algorithm which i can train on several invoices and then make predictions?

Comment: A neural network can have one input and mutiple outputs.

Comment: But can i map those output the input itself? if yes, then how?

Comment: You will have to train the model, but basically, a set of lstm input nodes with a few hidden layers and the output layer giving you the different outputs you need is one approach.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you are looking for NER (Named entity recognition). There are multiple free and paid tools available for intent and entity mapping. You can use Google DialogFlow, MS LUIS, or open source RASA for entity identification in given text.
if you want to develop your own solution then you can look at OpenNLP too.
Please revert on your observation on these wrt to your problem

Comment: I do not know how to make NER identifying proper nouns, names of cities, people, numbers, dates, etc. happen in Rasa. Can you please guide?

Answer (score 0):

What you are searching for is invoice data extraction ML. There are plenty of ML algorithms available, but none of them is done for your use case. Why? Because it is a very special use case. You can't just use Tensorflow and use sentences as input, although it can return multiple outputs.

You could use NLP (natural language processing) approaches to extract data. It is used by [Taggun](http://taggun.io/) to extract data from receipts. In that case, you can use only sentences. But you will still need to convert your sentences into NLP form (tokenization).

You could use deep learning (e.g. Tensorflow). In that case, you need to vectorize your sentences into vectors that can be input into a neural network. This approach needs much more creativity while there is no standard approach to do that. The goal is to describe every sentence as good as possible. But there is still one problem - how to parse dates, amounts, etc. Would it help NN if you would mark sentences with *contains_date* True/False? Probably yes.
A similar approach is used in invoice data extraction services like:

- [rossum.ai](https://rossum.ai)
- [typless.com](https://typless.com)

So if you are doing it for fun/research I suggest starting with a really simple invoice. Try to write a program that will extract invoice number, issue date, supplier and total amount with parsing and *if* statements. It will help you to define properties for feature vector input of NN. For example, *contains_date*, *contains_total_amount_word*, etc. See this [tutorial](https://elitedatascience.com/keras-tutorial-deep-learning-in-python) to start with NN.

If you are using it for work I suggest taking a look at one of the existing services for invoice data extraction.

Disclaimer: I am one of the creators of typless. Feel free to suggest edits.